# fullpage.js with jqueryui accordion: scroll to top after opening section

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js and want to include a jquery-ui accordion. In the accordion there will be quite long content so I use the fullpage.js option scrollOverflow: true.

How can I realize, that after scrolling to the bottom of the first accordion section and clicking on the button for accordion-section 2, the fullpage section should scroll to the top of the current accordion section.

Here is my codepen with an example:

```
(https://codepen.io/rrger/pen/JVEXLo)
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: did you find a solution?